# setRotationX und pivot point leads to weird result

Tags: android

I want to flip a view with the pivot point at the very top border. So what I am doing is this:

```
final TextView tvText = Views.find(this, R.id.tvText);
tvText.setPivotX(0);
tvText.setRotationX(45);
```

The view gets rotated on the x axes, just as expected. The strange thing is that the result is not symmetric anymore, the perspective distortion on the right is way stronger than on the left:

[image: rotated image]

I would like to have the skewing on both sides, not only on the right.
Any ideas?

-- EDIT --

Here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DrawActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00F0F0">

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#FF0F0F"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_touch_surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you want only RotationX.? and have you use `android:width="match_parent"`..???

Comment: yes, only rotationX and yes I ve used match_parent

Comment: @sroefln that's why its showing like this.

Comment: @SilentKiller No I don't think so- check my edits

Comment: try with only Rotation().

Comment: When i don't use the pivot point, then the view is rotated on the center. Thats not what i want

Answer (score 1):

xml: android:transformPivotX

or

code: setPivotX()

to half of the width (in your case 100dp). That will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use

```
tvText.setPivotX(tvText.getWidth()/2);
tvText.setPivotY(0);
```

for symmetry